# Changing font wont work on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

It seems I cant change font on my app. I have paste my font on ASSETS>FONTS but still now luck..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu2, container, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.kernel);
      Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),    "EVERAFTE.TTF");
      txt.setTypeface(font); 
    return v;
```

XML FILE

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/kernel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Kernel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: First, make sure that the capitalization of your filename matches what you are using in your Java code, and that the file exists in the root of your project's `assets/` directory. If that does not clear things up, try a different font, one that is known to work, like [this font](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Fonts/FontSampler/assets/fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf?raw=true) from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler). Not all fonts work in Android, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But even that font on the link doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),    "FONTS/EVERAFTE.TTF");

Answer (score 0):

first:

you should not set type face in onCreateView Method you need to do that after the view is created.

see:

```
TextView txt;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu2, container, false);
        txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.kernel);
        return v;


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),    "FONTS/EVERAFTE.TTF");
      txt.setTypeface(font); 
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and make sure the font path is true . (it is case sensitive).

---

edit:

create a custom TextView and use that in your Layout:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),    "FONTS/EVERAFTE.TTF");
                 setTypeface(font );
        }
    }

}
```

and then in xml file:

```
 <yourpackagename.MyTextView 
    android:id="@+id/kernel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Kernel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: @user3220085 sorry you have to write getContext()